# KML: Is there a way to define a folder once and then reference it like you do with styles?

Tags: directory, kml

I'm working with KML and have a macro that generates a KML from an Excel spreadsheet.  Right now, I loop through constructing the xml for each placemark.

**I'd like to be able to reference a folder id for each placemark** instead of having to nest placemarks within the  tags.

If I could just predefine the Folder element and reference it, that would save me some additional work with conditional statements in my macro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is No. It's not supported by the specs
See http://code.google.com/intl/nl-NL/apis/kml/documentation/kmlreference.html#placemark